# Ajax's PHP into while just working once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The code i'm trying to get to work is part of a price list of products from a db. It works almost all of it but i need one ajax to run multiple times, and it does, it even runs the success sentences but when i check the db its like it just ran once... i hope you can help me.

I take 2 values from inputs which are id and amount of the product, and i add them to the list when a button calls the send function, this is that part of the code:

```
function valores(cod, cant) {

if (cod != '') {
    cot.push([cod, cant]);
    i++;
}
return cot;
}

function send () {

event.returnValue=false; 

var id = $('#id').val();
var amount = $('#cant').val();
var total;


    if ($('#total').length > 0) {
        total = document.getElementById('total').value;
    } else {
        total = 0;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({cod : id, cant : amount, tot : total }),
        url: 'process/agprods.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#totals').remove();
            $('#prodsadded').append(data);
            valores(id, amount);
            rs = $(document.getElementById('rs').html);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#rs').innerHTML = rs;
            document.getElementById('note').innerHTML = "Error: The product doesn't exist.";
            $('#handler-note').click();
        }
    });
}
```

(I translated some words to english that are originaly in spanish and to make it more readable to you)

So, the cot[] array keeps the product's id and amount, to use them in the next code, which runs when the list is complete and you hit a save button that calls this function:

```
function ncotiza () {

  event.returnValue=false;

  var nlist = $('#codp').val();
  var day = $('#days').val();

  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({listnumber: nlist, days : day}),
    url: 'process/ncot.php'
  });

  j = 0;

  while (j <= i) {

      if (cot[j][0] != 0 && cot[j][1] != 0) {
          var num = cot[j][0];
          var cant = cot[j][1];

          $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: ({ listnumber : nlist, prodid: num, amount : cant }),
            url: 'process/ncotpro.php',
            success: function () {
                alert('Success');
            }
          });

          cot[j][0] = 0;
          cot[j][1] = 0;
          j++;
      }

      if (j == i) {
          window.location.reload(1);
          alert("Finished Successfully");
      };
  }

}
```

And it all runs fine, here's the PHP:

(ncot.php)

```
    $listnumber = isset($_POST["listnumber"]) ? $_POST["listnumber"] : '';
    $days = isset($_POST["days"]) ? $_POST["days"] : '';

    $cons = "INSERT INTO pricelist (listnumber, diashabiles, cdate)
                VALUES ('$listnumber', '$days', CURDATE())";
    mysql_query($cons);

    ?>
```

(ncotpro.php)

```
    $listnumber = isset($_POST["listnumber"]) ? $_POST["listnumber"] : '';
    $prodid = isset($_POST["prodid"]) ? $_POST["prodid"] : '';
    $amount = isset($_POST["amount"]) ? $_POST["amount"] : '';

    $cons = "SELECT price, um
                FROM inventory 
                WHERE listnumber = ".$prodid;

    $result = mysql_query($cons) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $umcons = mysql_query("SELECT uvalue FROM um WHERE id = ".$row["um"]) or die ("Error:".mysql_error());
    $umres = mysql_fetch_assoc($umcons);
    $vuum = $umres["uvalue"];
    $fprice = $row["price"] * ($amount * $vuum);

    $cons = "INSERT INTO cotpro (cotizacion, producto, amount, monto)
                VALUES ('$listnumber', '$prodid', '$amount', '$fprice')";

    mysql_query($cons) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    ?>
```

The first ajax runs ok, then it also does the one that's inside the while, and it throw all the alerts but when i check the db it just made 1 row and not all it has to.

I'm sorry if it's too obvious or something, i've look a lot of questions and answers in this page and i've been trying to fix this for hours but i just dont see it.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: In ncotpro.php, should this be 'WHERE listnumber = ".$listnumber;' instead of 'WHERE listnumber = ".$prodid;'?

I would also check the value of ajax success. Put "success: function(return) { alert('Success'); alert(return);}

Also, instead of "alert" I would log output to console with console.log()

Comment: It says **Uncaught** **TypeError:** **Cannot** **read** **property** **'0'** **of** **undefined** at this line:

`if (cot[j][0] != 0 && cot[j][1] != 0) {`
(on ncotiza inside the while)
why? it is declared...

Comment: Check variable scope and contents (is the variable within function scope or global scope?)

`console.log(cot[0]);` and `console.log(cot);`.

Comment: Something that will help you debug is to use clean code styling.
For example globals should be capitalised, and names should indicate their purpose.

What does variable `i` count? Could you tell me what this counts without looking at the code 1 month from now? 1 year? I would name this `PRODUCT_LIST_COUNTER` (capitalisation immediately tells me this is a global variable). Same thing with your function names (e.g. `send()`, send what?)

I'm not trying to be mean, its just that right now your code could be easier to read, and would make it easier for other people and yourself understand the code

Comment: You're right, Takuya. And don't worry you're not being mean. It's just a habit to name loop counters "i", "j" or "k". In this case i named "i" wrong because it's keeping a size value, not a loop counter. In fact, the Uncaught TypeError was because i had to put "while (j < i)" instead of "while (j <= i)". Now i don't see any errors in the log but still it's just saving 1 of the multiple ajaxs on the db. I really don't know what else can i do...

Comment: I got it, i'm sorry, it's not a code thing. I just set the table's indexes wrong /: thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the 2nd jquery file via firebug.
what the value you return in i

while (j <= i) {
 ..
 ..
 .